# Как выгрузить и использовать cookie с сервера на клиент

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

Я полностью сделал функционал cookie на backend(создание и удаление) но как его использовать на frontend ? Возможно есть статья или видео по этой теме, помогите пожалуйста. Хотел полностью разобраться в этой теме, например использовать куки для сохранения сессии

Comment: а для чего вам нужны куки ? и нужны ли вообще?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: устанавливаете соответствующий заголовок в HTTP Response и отправляете его клиенту... оттуда же получаете при запросе.

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin чтобы сохранять сессии

Comment: @Духсообщества я хочу углубленно разобраться в этой теме, поэтому это не конкретная проблема